# Mysql group concat on double join

Tags: mysql, group-concat, concatenation

I have a user table from which I want all values, so I have this query:

```
SELECT tbl_user.* FROM tbl_user
```

Now I want one additional column in this result which shows all roles this user has, (or nothing if there are no roles for the user). The role information comes from two additional tables.

The first table contains these two values: userid, roleid
The second table contains roleid and role_name.

So the group concat needs to get all role names based on the roleid's in table1.

I have tried several different ways to do this, but I don't succeed. Either I get only one result with several times the same rolename, or no result at all.

Thanks for your help

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: added `LEFT JOIN` for users with no role.

```
SELECT
  tbl_user.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(role_name) AS roles
FROM 
  tbl_user LEFT JOIN tbl_roles ON tbl_user.userid = tbl_roles.userid
  JOIN tbl_rolenames ON tbl_roles.roleid = tbl_rolenames.roleid
GROUP BY tbl_user.userid
```

Note that MySQL will permit a `GROUP BY` on fewer columns than appear in the `SELECT` list in total, but in other RDBMS you would need to explicitly list out the columns in `tbl_user` and include them in the `GROUP BY`, or do an additional self join against `tbl_user` to get the remaining columns from that table.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
  urole.userid,
  uall.username,
  uall.name,
  uall.othercols,
  urole.roles
FROM
  tbl_user uall JOIN (
  SELECT 
    tbl_user.userid, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(role_name) AS roles
  FROM 
    tbl_user LEFT JOIN tbl_roles ON tbl_user.userid = tbl_roles.roleid
    JOIN tbl_rolenames ON tbl_roles.roleid = tbl_rolenames.roleid
  GROUP BY tbl_user.userid
) urole ON uall.userid = urole.userid
```

Comment: @Michael Frey I already updated it with a `LEFT JOIN` to address that.

Comment: Just tried the Left Join version, but it still only returns those users that have a role assigned. (Trying the second select now)

Comment: Can you explain what the uall does/means on line 8? Is that a name given to the result of the join (select)?

Comment: @MichaelFrey `uall` is an alias given to `tbl_user` since it is used both in the outer SELECT and also in the inner SELECT to which it is joined.  I called it `uall` because it's purpose is to get the remaining columns from `tbl_user` other than `userid` which is retrieved from the inner query.

Comment: @MichaelFrey Note that I just added a `GROUP BY` clause to the query (second to last line) where I mistakenly omitted it before.