# Double results in GROUP_CONCAT with double JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I have the following tables:

**products**

- Fields: id, title
- Values: (1,'Product 1')

**table1**

- Fields: id, idProduct
- Values: (1,1),(2,1)

**table2**

- Fields: id, idProduct
- Values: (3,1),(4,1)

And the following query:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t1.id ORDER BY t2.id),
  GROUP_CONCAT(t2.id ORDER BY t2.id)
FROM
  products p
JOIN table1 t1 ON p.id=t1.idProduct
JOIN table2 t2 ON p.id=t2.idProduct
GROUP BY
  p.id
```

Expected result is:

```
1 | Product 1 | 1,2     | 3,4
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
1 | Product 1 | 1,1,2,2 | 3,3,4,4
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872351/mysql-group-concat-on-double-join

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add DISTINCT:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.id ORDER BY t2.id),
```